# Node.js dotenv in production

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, production, dotenv

I use dotenv package in my Node.js development environment. I'd like to continue using it in production. Is it okay to use .env file to set `NODE_ENV=production` and run it? If not - please elaborate.

Comment: Yeah, that's a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you're using them for. In production, environment variables are usually set by your hosting environment because anyone who has access to your codebase or git repository, can easily steal information like your hashing salt or JWT private key and use it to breach your app, but if you aren't storing any sensitive information it's perfectly fine :)

Comment: I wonder how are they going to steal it though, since .env files ought to be excluded from repositories. It's like the first thing to add to .gitignore alongside /node_modules, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it's not a good practice to store secrets in local files. Even though you exclude them from repositories, your secrets will still be available to anyone who can access your source code. That's why we use environment variables for holding them. It's just what I know.